# How does Vim guess background color on xterm?

Tags: vim, tmux, xterm

Vim has the ability to correctly guess the background color of an Xterm in order to set its internal option `bg` to either `dark` or `white` according to the terminal's one. Vim is able to do that correctly **only** when `TERM` is set to either `xterm`{,`-color`,`-256color`} or `linux` but no others like `tmux` or `screen`.

How does Vim to guess that?

I've found that most people forces setting up the `background` option to either `dark` or `light` in their `.vimrc` file; but I'd like a way to guess the same way Vim does, independently of the terminal being `xterm`, `tmux`, `screen`.

Comment: What is your OS? Is it debian/ubuntu? The setting may be defined in vim global rc scripts (in `/usr/share/vim`) or in sources of vim or in both. I can try to check recent ubuntu (16.04) vim sources, there is mention in debian/changelog (upstream patch) "6.1.136: When $TERM is "linux" the default for 'background' is "dark", even though the GUI uses a light background" http://ftp.twaren.net/vim/patches/6.1.136

Comment: Actually, using `TERM=xterm-256color` inside `tmux` still makes vim incorrectly guess the background color (I set it up by adding `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` in `~/.tmux.conf`)

Answer (score 14):

The default setting is defined (hard-coded) in Vim source code (written in the C programming language). There was a fix to not use "dark" in GUI variants of Vim with "linux" TERM since version 6.1.136, and it helps me to find actual code:

http://ftp.twaren.net/vim/patches/6.1.136

```
Patch 6.1.136
Problem:    When $TERM is "linux" the default for 'background' is "dark", even
        though the GUI uses a light background. (Hugh Allen)
Solution:   Don't mark the option as set when defaulting to "dark" for the
        linux console.  Also reset 'background' to "light" when the GUI
        has a light background.
Files:      src/option.c
```

The logic is here, default values: https://fossies.org/dox/vim-7.4/option_8c_source.html#l00566

```c
  563     {"background",  "bg",   P_STRING|P_VI_DEF|P_RCLR,
  564                 (char_u *)&p_bg, PV_NONE,
  565                 {
  566 #if (defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN3264)) && !defined(FEAT_GUI)
  567                 (char_u *)"dark",
  568 #else
  569                 (char_u *)"light",
  570 #endif
```

Detect terminal background: https://fossies.org/dox/vim-7.4/option_8c_source.html#l03754

```c
 3725     /* For DOS console the default is always black. */
 3726 #if !((defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN3264)) && !defined(FEAT_GUI))
 3727     /*
 3728      * If 'background' wasn't set by the user, try guessing the value,
 3729      * depending on the terminal name.  Only need to check for terminals
 3730      * with a dark background, that can handle color.
 3731      */
 3732     idx = findoption((char_u *)"bg");
 3733     if (idx >= 0 && !(options[idx].flags & P_WAS_SET)
 3734                          && *term_bg_default() == 'd')
 3735     {
 3736     set_string_option_direct(NULL, idx, (char_u *)"dark", OPT_FREE, 0);
 3737     /* don't mark it as set, when starting the GUI it may be
 3738      * changed again */
 3739     options[idx].flags &= ~P_WAS_SET;
 3740     }
 3741 #endif
 3754 /*
 3755  * Return "dark" or "light" depending on the kind of terminal.
 3756  * This is just guessing!  Recognized are:
 3757  * "linux"      Linux console
 3758  * "screen.linux"   Linux console with screen
 3759  * "cygwin"     Cygwin shell
 3760  * "putty"      Putty program
 3761  * We also check the COLORFGBG environment variable, which is set by
 3762  * rxvt and derivatives. This variable contains either two or three
 3763  * values separated by semicolons; we want the last value in either
 3764  * case. If this value is 0-6 or 8, our background is dark.
 3765  */
 3766     static char_u *
 3767 term_bg_default()
 3768 {
 3769 #if defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN3264)
 3770     /* DOS console nearly always black */
 3771     return (char_u *)"dark";
 3772 #else
 3773     char_u  *p;
 3774
 3775     if (STRCMP(T_NAME, "linux") == 0
 3776         || STRCMP(T_NAME, "screen.linux") == 0
 3777         || STRCMP(T_NAME, "cygwin") == 0
 3778         || STRCMP(T_NAME, "putty") == 0
 3779         || ((p = mch_getenv((char_u *)"COLORFGBG")) != NULL
 3780         && (p = vim_strrchr(p, ';')) != NULL
 3781         && ((p[1] >= '0' && p[1] <= '6') || p[1] == '8')
 3782         && p[2] == NUL))
 3783     return (char_u *)"dark";
 3784     return (char_u *)"light";
 3785 #endif
 3786 }
```

GUI fix:

```c
 4044 gui_bg_default()
 4045 {
 4046     if (gui_get_lightness(gui.back_pixel) < 127)
 4047     return (char_u *)"dark";
 4048     return (char_u *)"light";
 4049 }
```

UPDATE:
For vim-7.4.1689 (debian/ubuntu) I rebuilt Vim package with debugging info (`-O2 -g` default option; before strip and pack into deb) and ran `TERM=xterm gdb --args vim-7.4.1689/src/vim-basic/vim -e` with `watch p_bg`. First change of `p_bg` was by `term_bg_default()` to `light`, and second is from ... `main`: `may_req_termresponse()` (if FEAT_TERMRESPONSE was defined) -> `vpeekc_nomap` -> `vpeekc` -> `vgetorpeek` -> **`check_termcode`** -> `set_option_value("bg",..)` -> `set_string_option`.

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/54c10ccf9274880e83093a99690e7bfa9a2d2fa8/src/term.c

Line 3302 - `may_req_bg_color()` color, called from `main.c` just after `starttermcap()` / log message "start termcap"; I added preprocessed definition of the request:

```c
/*
 * Similar to requesting the version string: Request the terminal background
 * color when it is the right moment.
 */
    void
may_req_bg_color(void)
...

    {(int)KS_RBG,   "\033]11;?\007",

    {(int)KS_RBG,   "[RBG]"},
```

Line 4286 - handle response from termcap request:

```c
check_termcode( ....

    /* Check for background color response from the terminal:
     *
     *       {lead}11;rgb:{rrrr}/{gggg}/{bbbb}{tail}
     *
     * {lead} can be <Esc>] or OSC
     * {tail} can be '\007', <Esc>\ or STERM.
     *
     * Consume any code that starts with "{lead}11;", it's also
     * possible that "rgba" is following.
     */

        if (i - j >= 21 && STRNCMP(tp + j + 3, "rgb:", 4) == 0
            && tp[j + 11] == '/' && tp[j + 16] == '/'
            && !option_was_set((char_u *)"bg"))
        {/* TODO: don't set option when already the right value */
            LOG_TR("Received RBG");
            rbg_status = RBG_GOT;
            set_option_value((char_u *)"bg", 0L, (char_u *)(
                (3 * '6' < tp[j+7] + tp[j+12] + tp[j+17])
                ? "light" : "dark"), 0);
            reset_option_was_set((char_u *)"bg");
```

Added by 7.4.757 patch http://ftp.vim.org/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.757

```
Patch 7.4.757
Problem:    Cannot detect the background color of a terminal.
Solution:   Add T_RBG to request the background color if possible. (Lubomir
            Rintel)
Files:      src/main.c, src/term.c, src/term.h, src/proto/term.pro

#define T_RBG   (term_str(KS_RBG))  /* request background RGB */
```

Your tmux/screen may not implement '[RBG]' request; check by running in xterm and in tmux and compare outputs:

```
echo -e '\033]11;?\007'
```

---

You may define COLORFGBG (and there were bugs about it in neovim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2764)
There is bug report for gnome-terminal to set it
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733423

> Various terminals, including urxvt and konsole, set an environment variable "COLORFGBG" to allow applications to detect the foreground and background colors.  Various programs, such as Vim, use this to determine whether to use a color scheme that works best on a light or dark background.  Please consider setting this variable in gnome-terminal as well.

Egmont has some option in the bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733423 to set `COLORFGBG` with `.bashrc`.

You may change this in your "vimrc" (`~/.vimrc`), or globally on your OS by changing `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` or in vim sources by recompiling custom version or in Vim sources by reporting a bug to Vim authors / sending them patches.

The [documentation of "bg"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'bg') describes part of logic and gives solutions for vimrc:

> When setting 'background' to the default value with:
>
> ```
>   :set background&
> ```
>
> Vim will guess the value.  In the GUI this should work correctly,
>     in other cases Vim might not be able to guess the right value.
>
> When starting the GUI, the default value for '`background`' will be
>       `"light"`.  When the value is not set in the `.gvimrc`, and Vim detects
>       that the background is actually quite dark, '`background`' is set to
>       `"dark"`.  ....
>
> Normally this option would be set in the `.vimrc` file.  Possibly
>       depending on the terminal name.  Example:
>
> ```
>       :if &term == "pcterm"
>         :  set background=dark
>         :endif
> ```
>
> When this option is set, the default settings for the highlight groups
>       will change.  To use other settings, place "`:highlight`" commands AFTER
>       the setting of the 'background' option.

Comment: And there is doc: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'bg' "When setting 'background' to the default value with:
  `:set background&`
  Vim **will guess the value**.  In the GUI this should work correctly,
 in other cases *Vim might not be able to guess the right value*."

Comment: Vim version 7.4; OS GNU/Linux Debian; COLORFGBG has no value. My terminal is ROXTerm and has set TERM to xterm-256color, but that value is overridden by Tmux to tmux-256color.

I see in the source code that bg is set to dark when TERM is linux, screen.linux, cygwin or putty. I don't see the exact part where xterm is taken into account.

The case I am trying to define is when TERM is set to `xterm` and ROXTerm has white bg, Vim sets bg to light and when ROXTerm has black bg, Vim sets bg to dark; not depending on the TERM value. When TERM is `tmux-256color` bg in Vim is always light.

Comment: Baco, I checked value of "bg" setting when `TERM=xterm` with `vim -u none -U none` and it is "light". So, when `TERM=xterm` is was set by source code of vim to light, and then, by some vim default startup script reset to "dark". Still unable to find it or find how to trace all commands executed by scripts.

Comment: Baco, there is also ansi request `echo -e '\033]11;?\007'` done by vim to detect bg color since 7.4.757 patch: http://ftp.vim.org/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.757; aslo mentioned here: https://lwn.net/Articles/664943/. I tested it in my xterm and gnome-terminal and it worked with `11;rgb:0000/0000/0000`; but it doesn't in mate-terminal. This sequence is one of xterm's `ctlseqs`: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls `OSC Ps ; Pt BEL` ... `Ps = 1 1  -> Change VT100 text background color to Pt.` "For colors and font, if Pt is a "?", the
          control sequence elicits a response which consists of the con-
          trol sequence which would set the corresponding value.". Also some descriptions at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172548/how-to-determine-the-current-color-of-the-console-output "How to determine the current color of the console output?", 2014

Comment: osgx, that I think, is the answer. I've found that every terminal in which Vim was able to set `bg` correctly are the ones where the ANSI escape sequence works. In my case mate-terminal 1.14 was able to return the RGB values and Vim detected correctly the bg color also, but Guake Terminal was not. Obviously Tmux is having similar troubles.

Comment: This is, by far, the best and most comprehensive explanation of how Vim attempts to detect background colour that I have found anywhere.