# Determine terminal/TTY background color at runtime

Tags: node.js, terminal, tty, chalk

Using the chalk library to stylize/colorize the terminal.

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

if I use:

```
console.log(chalk.blue('foobar'));
```

that's totally readable in a terminal with a light background, but totally unreadable in a terminal with a dark background.

Is there some way to determine the background color of a terminal at runtime?

---

Example given:

The `"npm notice"` log level is a case of this problem:

[image]

It's difficult to read the blue on black.

Comment: There's no portable method.  For xterm (and *some* of the terminals that imitate it), there's [DECRQSS](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Device-Control-functions) asking for the current **`SGR`** settings.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a generic answer, about **[ANSI Escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)** in the **tty context**.

To highlight a specific sequence by swapping the backgroud/foreground, so it stay readable on all color schemes, use **code 7 Reverse video**.

This way there is no need to prior knows the palette and adapt.

Example *in bash*, using reverse video:

```
echo -e "\033[7mHello world\e[0m"
```

This can be chained, reverse video, and a red background:

```
echo -e "\033[31;7mHello world\e[0m"
```

This will always be readable on any background, like the second line of this gif:

[image]

> Reverse video is commonly used in software programs as a visual aid to
>   highlight a selection that has been made as an aid in preventing
>   description errors, where an intended action is performed on an object
>   that is not the one intended. It is more common in modern desktop
>   environments to change the background to other colors such as blue, or
>   to use a semi-transparent background to "highlight" the selected text.
>   On a terminal understanding ANSI escape sequences, the reverse video
>   function is activated using the escape sequence CSI **7 m** (which equals
>   **SGR 7**).
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_video

From my own answer: [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365998/2494754) , a question with a lot of informations about ***ansi sequences***.

Comment: How do you do this with chalk specifically?