# Is there a way to get current user system colors in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to do this? I've searched all over and can't come up with anything. For instance, if the user's current window or window text color is black, how would I find that out programmatically?

**EDIT:**

I'm currently working on a project that parses Excel documents in Nodejs. According to [this documentation](https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/Part4/OOXML_P4_DOCX_ST_SystemColorVal_topic_ID0EL1MOB.html?hl=st_systemcolorval), themes pull system colors for the current user. I'm aware that CSS2 had pretty much identical system color properties, but I need to know how to get that information within the context of my Nodejs program. So if the Excel file is stating "windowText," what would I use in Nodejs (if anything) to extract that information from the user's system profile? As far as I know, it's nothing to do with the terminal, but I could be wrong.

**EDIT 2**

The proposed answer/dupe at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color) does not answer my question for two reasons:

1. This has nothing to do with **Nodejs, the library I'm specifically asking for** (at least not that I could see)
2. This answers how to find and manipulate terminal colors. Believe it or not, I actually know how to do that and it doesn't solve this problem for me. If one could elaborate how I could implement that solution into a **Nodejs** Excel parsing program to progrommatically pull actual color information from a user's system profile, I'd love to read it

Please review the edit along with the linked documentation above for more information about what I'm actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color

Comment: @Jacob are you asking for the terminal color (based on your nodejs tag) et the CSS color of the browser page ? (in this case your tags are wrong, and should be html/css)

Comment: @Arthur see edit in question

Comment: If you are on windows (which I think you are, since you want to do something with excel) you probably want to use some [WinAPI functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor). However it's not really clear to me, what setting exactly you want to get