# Is there a way to know background color of terminal in c?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, ansi-escape

I'm creating a c program which colors some text using ANSI escape sequence arguments like `printf("\e[38;2;r;g;bm");` in Ubuntu;
The problem is that the text get invisible if the background of the console matches with the foreground. If I print a text in black color in a white background it's perfectly visible but when the same code ran on a black background, the text is invisible.

So my plan is to get the terminal background color during runtime and choose text color accordingly.

Is there a way to get the background color of terminal in c?

Comment: You can't read much back from the terminal other than its size.

Comment: @tadman ncurses keeps this data internally. So if you use this library you can get this data

Comment: Have you tried to [request the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540928/1983398)?

Answer (score 2):

`ncurses` library keeps the windows and terminal data in its own buffers. If you use this library you can read the character and it's attributes. Use function
[`inch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) or similar

Comment: The more of this stuff you do, the more you'll wish you're using ncurses, or the more of ncurses you'll have painfully re-written.